# Сохранение изображений в телефон пользователя

Tags: java, android, изображения, gallery, imageview

Добрый день.
В моем приложении есть несколько Активити, некоторые из них с фотографиями. 
Я хочу сделать доступ по паролю и при запуске первой Активити открывать **ProgressDialog**, во время которого с сервера будут загружать изображения и текстовая информация.

Текстовую информацию можно сохранить в **SharedPreferences**. А как можно сохранить (впоследствии выводить пользователю на экран; доступ в приложение и к информации в нем должен быть и без Интернета) изображения?

Можно каждый раз скачивать из сервера при заходе в приложение, но это не вариант. Также, наверное, возможно, сохранить в Галерею и показывать оттуда. Но это тоже не подходит.

В связи с этим **вопрос**: как можно сохранить скачанное изображение в каком-то месте (настоятельно важно, чтобы пользователь не смог увидеть изображения в Галерее), чтобы оно после отобразилось в приложении даже без доступа в Интернет?

Comment: Используйте, например, внутреннюю память устройства. https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20download%20file%20into%20internal%20storage&es_th=1

Comment: @metalurgus , спасибо за совет! Я думал об этом, но будет ли при этом показываться изображение в Галерее в общем списке? Или же, например, показываться, как фотографии WhatsApp, в отдельной папке в Галерее, созданной для приложения?

Comment: И самое главное: как доставать это изображение, чтобы поставить в тот же ImageView? .setBackgroundResource ? А как путь указать?

Comment: вам опять ссылку в гугл дать? Может сами поискать попробуете?

Comment: @metalurgus , этот сайт для того и существует, чтобы помогать, а не пересылать на поисковики. Но, в любом случае, спасибо за совет.

Comment: Да, существует, но часто под *помощью* пытаются просто сесть на голову.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно кэшировать.

Создайте класс какой-нить для работы с кэшем. У меня что-то такое в старом проекте было:

```
public static class FileHelper{
        private static final String IMAGE_STORAGE = "images";


        private static enum StorageType {INTERNAL, EXTERNAL};
        private static StorageType preferStorage = StorageType.EXTERNAL;

        private static final Map<String, Bitmap> cache = Collections.synchronizedMap(new LinkedHashMap<String, Bitmap>());

          private final static int MAX_CACHED = 50;
        /**
         * Number of bytes in one KB = 2<sup>10</sup>
         */
        private final static long SIZE_KB = 1024L;

        /**
         * Number of bytes in one MB = 2<sup>20</sup>
         */
        public final static long SIZE_MB = SIZE_KB * SIZE_KB;

        private static final long NEEDED_PLACE = 2;

        /**
         * Доступна ли внешняя память для записи
         * @return
         */
        public static boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
            String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
            if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        /**
         * Доступна ли внешняя память для чтения
         * @return
         */
        public static boolean isExternalStorageReadable() {
            String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
            if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) ||
                Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }


        private static boolean hasExternalAvailableSpace(Context c) {
            StatFs stat = new StatFs(c.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getPath());
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
                long sdAvailSize = (long) stat.getAvailableBlocksLong()
                        * (long) stat.getBlockSizeLong();
                sdAvailSize = (long)(sdAvailSize*1.F/ SIZE_MB); 
                return sdAvailSize > NEEDED_PLACE;
            } else {
                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                double sdAvailSize = (double) stat.getAvailableBlocks()
                        * (double) stat.getBlockSize();
                sdAvailSize/=SIZE_MB;
                return sdAvailSize > NEEDED_PLACE;
            }

        }

        public static String getImagePath(Context c, String id){

            String dir;
            // чекаем во внешней памяти
            dir = getExtImageStorageDir(c).getAbsolutePath();
            File file = new File(dir+"/"+id+".png");

            // если есть, берём её
            if(file.exists() ) return file.getAbsolutePath() ;

            // иначе чекаем во внутренней памяти
            dir = getIntImageStorageDir(c).getAbsolutePath();
            file = new File(dir+"/"+id+".png");

            // возвращаем
            if (file.exists()) 
                return file.getAbsolutePath();
            else 
                throw new NoSuchElementException(file.getAbsolutePath());
        }


        public static Bitmap getImage(Context c, String id){
            synchronized (cache) {
                // если ещё нет в кеше битмапа с этим изображением
                if (!cache.containsKey("img"+id)) {
                    try {
                        Bitmap img = null;
                        String imgPath;

                        imgPath = getImagePath(c, id);
                        // тогда декодим из файла
                        img = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgPath);
                        // добавляем в кэш
                        cache.put("img"+id, img);
                        return img;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
                return cache.get("img"+id);
            }
        }



        public static boolean WriteImage(Context c, Bitmap img, String id) {

            File dir = getImagePreferStorageDir(c);
            String filename = dir.getAbsolutePath() +"/"+id+".png";
            FileOutputStream outputStream;
            for(File f :dir.listFiles())
                if(f.getName().substring(0, f.getName().indexOf(".png")).equals(id))
                    return true;

            try {
                cache.put("img"+id, img);
                outputStream = new FileOutputStream(filename);
                ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                img.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();

                outputStream.write(byteArray);
                outputStream.close();
                return true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
        }



        public static File getImagePreferStorageDir(Context c) {
            if(preferStorage == StorageType.EXTERNAL && isExternalStorageWritable() && hasExternalAvailableSpace(c))
                return getExtImageStorageDir(c);
            else
                return getIntImageStorageDir(c);
        }


        public static File getExtImageStorageDir(Context c) {

            File file = new File(c.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), IMAGE_STORAGE);
            if(file.exists());
            else
                if (!file.mkdirs());
            return file;
        }


        public static File getIntImageStorageDir(Context c) {

            File file = new File(c.getFilesDir(), IMAGE_STORAGE);
            if(file.exists())
                ;
            else
                if (!file.mkdirs());

            return file;
        }


        private static void deleteFolder(File file){
            if (file.exists()){
                for(File f:file.listFiles())
                    f.delete();

                file.delete();
            }

        }
        public static void  clearCache(){
            LOG.d("clear cache");
            cache.clear();
        }


        public static void clear(Context c){
            deleteFolder(getIntImageStorageDir(c));
            deleteFolder(getExtImageStorageDir(c));
            clearCache();

        }
    }
```

Я там немного комментарием добавил, чтоб понятнее было.

Логика такая:

1. Проверяете `FileHelper.getImagePath`. Если нет файла, будет исключение. Тогда качаете изображение с сети.
2. Скачиваете изображение.
3. Сохраняете `FileHelper.WriteImage`. Изображение и на диск сохранится, и в памяти в кеше будет. Можете поменять логику, убрать вообще кеш в памяти, всегда грузить с диска. В зависимости от выбора, сейвиться будет или во внешнюю, или во внутреннюю память.
4. Если же в 1 пункте не было исключения, то получайте его `FileHelper.getImage`.

Может всё упростить. Задать явно, чтоб только внешняя память использовалось, в разы кода меньше будет. Может in memory cache убрать. Я лишь показываю направление )

Comment: спасибо за столь подробный ответ) И, все же, осталось пара вопросов: если я буду просто сохранять изображение на внутреннюю память (для меня код кэша выглядит пока что сложновато, буду пытаться разбираться, но приложение нужно писать сейчас), а потом доставать его, **будет ли оно сохранено в Галерее у пользователя?** Для меня это достаточно важно. **И какой метод мне использовать?** Будет ли это похоже на примерно следующее: Image_view.setBackgroundResource(....)? И последний вопрос: **что указывать вместо точек? Путь вида dir+"/"+id+".png"** ?

Comment: @Dmitry что за "галерея пользователя"? Приложение стандартное для просмотра изображений? Если вы будете сохранить во внутреннюю память, то в галерее не будет видно их. `image_view.setBackground(FileHelper.getImage(context, id))` для установки изображения.